# How can I easily force a browser refresh without going into settings, clearing all caches?

Tags: chrome-for-android, browser

On my Windows 11 PC Firefox browser, if I want to refresh my webpage and load the new style.css that I uploaded instead of using old cached one, I can do "control- [click on browser page refresh icon]"

On an Android device, with Chrome for example, is there an easy way to force a reload of the webpage and style.css instead of going into Settings and clearing all caches?

Comment: Maybe you can look at some of the options posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571213/how-can-i-force-a-hard-reload-in-chrome-for-android).